# Change cipher suite in Elastic Beanstalk tomcat7

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, tomcat7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I need to enable one of both:

- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
- TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384

When I call a third party API I receive handshake exception.
In localhost I resolved it adding the JCE Package for Java 7 to enable newer cipher suites, but, in elastic beanstalk environment it didn't work and I received the same error.

Beanstalk configuration:
64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.4.3 running Tomcat 7 Java 7

I thought in change the server.xml and set *Connector* configs, but in localhost I didn't make this and work's fine.

Anybody have an ideia?

**PS**: Java 7 inside elastic beanstalk environment is open-jdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first: in my opinion elastic beanstalk it's a sucks.
- have not a lot of support in foruns and community
- it's hard to understand lifecycles and hooks
- isn't immutable, persist files among deploys

I couldn't solve this problem in AWS.

I fixed this updating java 7 to java 8.